How to prevent dotnet format from applying default values to configs not defined in .editorconfig?
My .editorconfig looks like below with only two configs defined:
[*.{cs}]
indent_size = 2
csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = true

However, when running dotnet format whitespace in my project, I found that dotnet format applied many other configs with their default values. And those configs are not defined in my .editorconfig like csharp_new_line_before_else. Is there a way to prevent dotnet format from doing so and only format what are defined in .editorconfig?
Already covered above.
